# chef-client delayed until end of recipe

Tags: chef

I have a recipe that looks like the following:

```
service "xyz" do
  :action nothing
end

file "xyz.conf" do
   ...
   notfies :restart, "service[xyz]", delayed
end

file "xyz.props" do
   ...
   notfies :restart, "service[xyz]", delayed
end
```

As you can see delayed notification is a good way to make sure restart is only triggered once and only when changes , but my issue is delayed notifications are triggered at the end of chef-client run, I have recipes that follow this one that need the service restarted, is there a way I can do an end-of-recipe restart?

Currently I am looking at perhaps examining `run_context.delayed_notification_collection` to see if a service is being notified and using that in a guard.

so at end of recipe I can do:

```
service "xyz" do
  action :restart
  only_if notification_for("service_restart")
end
```

Does anyone have better ideas?

Comment: Could you wrap all of your file resources into a LWRP with `use_inline_resources` and then have the LWRP notify `service[xyz]` to restart immediately?

Answer (score 0):

I wound up using node.run_state to set a flag for restart.  My resources that modified configuration would notify a ruby block that basically set a flag such as node.run_state[:SVC_restart] = true.  And then at the end the service would be created with :restart action and a guard to check if that flag exists and is set.